# Android API Target Level 5 and 6 for Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, api, ubuntu

Today i installed Ubuntu 10.4 and Eclipse Galileo. Then I downloaded the Android SDK and tried to install all packages via the Android SDK Tools. But unfortunately, only the Target Levels 3, 4, 7 and 8 were available. API Level 5 and 6 are missing.

Does anybody know the reason for this? I already did a Google search and there seems to be nobody with the same problem. I also tried to restart it and nothing happens, the API Levels are still missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anybody know the reason for this?

They are deprecated and generally unnecessary. Android 2.0 and 2.0.1 are used on [approximately 0.4% of Android production devices](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html).

That being said, uncheck "Display updates only" in the Available Packages area of the Android SDK and AVD Manager, and you will see them.

Comment: thanks that solved the problem. but i never had this issue using windows xp/vista/7.